# POST JsonArray using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, sendgrid

I have a JSON Array that I am trying to post to SENDGRID using Ajax. Using Postman I am able to post with no issues however when I post the data in my .js file I keep getting an error (bad request = missing parameters).

Any help is appreciated.

**Note:** The values are in fact valid. I have removed the identifying information for safety.

CHROME PAYLOAD:

[image]

AJAX Call:

```
var mailUrl = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send";
var postdata = '{"personalizations": [{"to":[{"to email"}],"from": {"email":"from email"},"subject":"Hello, World!" , "content" : [{ "type":"text/plain" , "value":"TestMessage!" }]}]}'
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer APIKEY"},
    url: mailUrl,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    success: function (res) {
         alert('ok');
    },
    error: function (res) {
         alert('problems');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with this part of json `[{"to":[{"to email"}]`.You can use [**jsonlint**](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate the json. Also `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string.

But in your case `postdata` is already a string .

Comment: I solved my own issue (couldn't close the question) but this was pretty damn close so I'll chose you.

Answer (score 0):

The string stored in the variable  is a valid JSON. Calling `JSON.stringify()` on a JSON will escape all the special characters like `"` and that escaped string will not be deserialized to the object you intended.

While a string is still a valid JSON according to some specifications, The specifications for `application/json` stated in RFC4627

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
>      surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).

make the returned string invalid for post.

Sending the string itself without serializing it again will likely work.

Comment: Even doing that I still am getting rejected.